# ibatis java.util.Map parameters with dot(.) character

Tags: java, ibatis

I have a parameters Map with property name "xx.xx", but Ibatis cannot know property named "xx.xx" ("xxxx" is ok).

how can I use Map property with name contains dot(.) character? or I have to remove the dot(.).

Thanks very much

Thang Hoang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iBatis uses JavaBean naming conventions, and "xx.xx" isn't a valid JavaBean property name. I think you're going to have to change those map keys to something more conventional, before feeding it to iBatis.

Answer (score 0):

OGNL will treat it as a property(see ASTProperty), use map.get('aaa.bbb') will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like [this ("Get value from bean within a bean")](http://code.google.com/p/bean-property-controller/wiki/Examples) which is what my [BeanPropertyController](http://code.google.com/p/bean-property-controller/) does? I don't know if this is even possible with IBATIS, but I know my utility can do that... :)